# Physical interpretation of the relative displacement tensor?

Tags: classical-mechanics, tensor-calculus, stress-strain

I've resolved a relative displacement tensor into a strain tensor and a rotation tensor, where

the strain tensor is:
$$
 \varepsilon_{i,j} =\begin{pmatrix} 0.2 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0.8 &0.4\\0&0.4&0.4\end{pmatrix}
$$

and the rotation tensor is:
$$
\omega_{i,j} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 &-0.2\\0&0.2&0\end{pmatrix}
$$

How would these conditions physically change a small cube (with respect to the Cartesian cooridates (x,y,z) ?

Comment: Are you talking about the displacement gradient? Relative displacement (in the Galilean sense) would be a vector, not a 2nd order tensor.

Answer (score 1):

To the extent that all your matrix elements are <<1, these rotation and strain parameters are doing the matrix transformation (think of the cube being centered on the origin, and M being applied to vectors going to the corners of the cube):

$$
M=I+ \epsilon + \omega
$$

This matrix would simultaneously

Strain (stretch) the box fractionally by .2 in x, .8 in y, and .4 in z

Strain (parallelepiped) the box in the yz plane such that if you stick the x axis in your eye you will see the sides of the parallelepiped both rotated inward by .4 radians from the y and z axis.

and

Rotate the box by .2 radians about the x-axis.